# Why doesn't (&array)[i] take the address of the ith element?

Tags: c++, arrays

Consider the following code

```
int tab2[2];
tab2[0]=5;
tab2[1]=3;
std::cout << tab2[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << (&tab2)[1] << std::endl;
```

As I have read in other topics, an array can decay to pointer at its first element. Then why doesn't the [] doesn't work the same for tab2 and &tab2 in the above code? What is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already "converted" as a pointer. You can use the `[]` notation with arrays or pointers...

`(&tab2)` means you get the address of your array... In a pointer perspective, it's a pointer to a pointer ( `**` ).

So you are trying to convert a variable (which is an array) as a pointer. Ok, but then you try to access the `[1]` element, which of course does not exist, as your pointer points to your array's address... Such a notation would expect a second array.

Comment: Yup, so try `&tab2[1]` that's again the same address.

Comment: Actually, [`&(tab2)[1]`](http://ideone.com/GePaj) and [`(&tab)[1]`](http://ideone.com/dST73) are different.

Comment: This is confused at best ... or simply incorrect. The OP asked about `(&tab2)[1]`, not `&(tab2)[1]`. Even more, there is no array-to-pointer decay in `&tab2`, and the type of this expression is not pointer to pointer, but pointer to array `int (*)[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

This expression:

```
(&tab2)[1]
```

Gets you a pointer to an array of 2 ints. Then uses array syntax on that pointer-to-an-array to get you the 1st 2 element int array after tab2.

So you have in memory

```
          tab2

          0         1   // index into tab2
          5         3   // values
```

You get a pointer to the array

```
          0         1
 &tab2 -> 5         3
```

Then you go 1 array of 2 ints past tab2

```
          0         1         2        3
 &tab2 -> 5         3         ?        ?
                             /|\
                              (&tab2)[1]
```

Comment: "Since tab2 decays to a pointer what you've done is taken the address of the decayed to pointer." - not true, see my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `(&tab2)`, you are retrieving the address of your array. Your statement itself answers your question.
Had you used `(*(&tab2))`, you would have got what you were expecting as output - `3`.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done by adding address-of (&) to tab2 is given yourself the memory address of the tab2 pointer, or a pointer to a pointer (int**).  So logically, yes, indexing it makes sense.  However, &tab2 is not the same as tab2.  &tab2 points to the pointer itsefl, while tab2 points to the array.  By indexing &tab2 with 1, you've told it to look at the next element in sequence, which doesn't exist (or it does exist, but belongs to another variable).  Had you indexed it with 0, this would have been fine as you would be looking at the "root" of the memory sequence.

Indexing just tab2 is fine as well obviously, because it points to an array.